# Windows Phone-cannot declare instance members in a static class in C#

Tags: c#, static, windows-phone, contacts

Hi I'm new in `Windows phone development` and I do some exercises to learn how to develop.
I tried to use the ContactManager class to get device's contact and I get this error:

> cannot declare instance members in a static class 'Contact Manager'

My class is not a `static`,so why it still show me this error?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mytextblock.Text = "Hi";
        }
        public void GetContacts()
        {
            ContactManager theContactManager = new ContactManager();
            foreach (Contact theContact in theContactManager.GetContactCollection())
            {
                string theLine = theContact.Names[0].FormattedName;
                foreach (PhoneNumber theNumber in theContact.PhoneNumbers)
                    theLine += "\t" + theNumber.ToString();
                listBox1.Items.Add(theLine);
                //Console.WriteLine(theLine); //Uncomment this if on console
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At least tell us on which line this happens. Post the full error message.

Comment: At this line :
ContactManager theContactManager = new ContactManager();

Comment: Unlikely. Again, post (copy/paste) the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's static: `public static class ContactManager`.

Click on "C#" to view declaration:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactmanager.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: yes I check this out too, So How I use the Contact Manager to get the device's contacts?

Comment: Do you know or at least understand C++ CLI?

Comment: If so, here is a usage example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-manager-API-sample-319bdcef/sourcecode?fileId=86609&pathId=440388044

Comment: your example shows how to add a contact, I try to get all contacts

Comment: What you can do is use JustDecompile to get a glimpse of the source code of the involved .NET Assemblies and maybe understand how ContactManager works. I personally have never used ContactManager myself, that is why I can't tell you right now how to use it.